# Independence of the components of a random vector

Tags: probability

Let

$\varphi_{X,Y}(\theta_1,\theta_2)=e^{-i\theta_1}e^{-(\theta_1^2+4\theta_1\theta_2+5\theta_2^2)}$

the characteristic function of a random vector
$
\begin{pmatrix}
X\cr
Y
\end{pmatrix}$.

(a) Calculate $\mathbb{P}(2X-Y<1)$.

(b) Determine whether the components of the vector

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
e^{5X-2Y}\cr
\sin\left(Y-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)
\end{pmatrix}$$

are independent.

(a) I've observed that $\varphi_{X,Y}(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ is the characteristic function of a gaussian random vector with vector of expectation $\mu=\begin{pmatrix}
1\cr 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
$ and covariance matrix $C=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 4 \cr 4 & 10
\end{pmatrix}$$
$

So, the vector $\begin{pmatrix}
X\cr
2X-Y
\end{pmatrix}$$
$
is also a gaussian random vector because is an affine transformation of $\begin{pmatrix}
X\cr
Y
\end{pmatrix}$$
$ (multiplying it for the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \cr
2 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$
$)

So, $2X-Y$ is a random gaussian variable with expectation $2$ and variance $2$ (it's easy to calculate it).

So I've procedeed to standardize $2X-Y$ and I used tha standard normal boards.

(b) I think I have no way of saying that the vector is gaussian, so, the only way I thought is to find the joint density, trying to reverse the diffeomeorphism in the canonic way, but it becomes very complicated to get to the end of the calculations.

Are you agree with me on point (a)? Suggestions for (b)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic on part (a) is right. For part (b), remember that for a jointly Gaussian random vector, if the components are uncorrelated, they are independent. Further remember that if two random vectors are independent, any (measurable) functions of them are also independent. Thus, (b) boils down to check whether $5X - 2Y$ and $Y$ are independent or not, further check whether or not they are uncorrelated, and they are indeed uncorrelated by showing

$[5,-2;0,1] * [2,4;4,10]* [5,-2;0,1]' = [10,0;0,10]$

Comment: Thank you a lot! In the end can I still calculate the covariance with the definition? The matrix you find is that of the vector $[5X  -2Y, Y]$?

Comment: @SigmaAlgebra Yes, you can directly calculate the cross-covariance between 5x-2y and y. Here how I get this matrix is as follows, [5x-2y;y] = [5,-2;0,1]*[x;y], and the off-diagonal of the results is exactly the cross-covariance

Comment: Clear, thanks!!